# Pandas dataframe - 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boolean, typeerror

I am trying to retrieve records in a dataframe that do not have matching IDs in a separate list. Essentially, I want to drop any records from the dataframe where UniqueId matches any Ids in the list PM_docIDs:

```
df = df[~df['UniqueId']].isin((PM_docIDs).index, inplace=True)
```

This produces the following error:

```
In  [35]:
Line 4:     df = df[~df['UniqueId']].isin((PM_docIDs).index, inplace=True)

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there an easier way to do this or is there something I can do to fix the snippet aboveso I don't get the TypeError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but your syntax is a little jumbled.  How about this?

```
df = df[~df['UniqueId'].isin(PM_docIDs.index)]
```

Comment: same error :( Line 6:     df = df[~df['UniqueId'].isin(PM_docIDs.index)]

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Hmmm are you sure you have `df` defined correctly?  What is the output of `type(df)`?

Comment: Looks like I accidentally converted it to boolean? I reran cells and now I get this: TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [builtin_function_or_method]

Comment: What code did you run to produce this new error?  Did you try the line I posted above?

Comment: df = df[~df['UniqueId'].isin(PM_docIDs.index)]

Comment: Alrighty, so what is `PM_docIDs` then? What does `type(PM_docIDs)` give?

Comment: It's a list that was generated from a table using a search cursor

Comment: Ah, then you don't need the `.index` piece.  Just `df = df[~df['UniqueId'].isin(PM_docIDs)]`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Frodnar. All the examples I found had that index bit in it. You want to edit answer and I'll check it?

Comment: Great!  Can you mark my answer as accepte3d?

Comment: Just did. Now on to the next hurdle. Thank you!